# Generalisation of kth derivative to real values of k

Tags: derivatives

The answer to this question is most likely no, but I'm asking anyway: Assume that $f\in C^n(\mathbb {R,R})$. Is their any *natural* generalisation of the map $$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to C(\mathbb{R, R})\\k\mapsto f^{(k)}$$
to a map
$$
[1, n]\to\{g\colon\mathbb{R\to R}\}\\
x\mapsto f^{(x)}?
$$
That is, can we generalise "the $k$th derivative" to "the $x$th derivative" for real values of $x$? What I mean by "natural" is: Anything that has desirable properties and that has been explicitly formulated by someone, somewhere.

Comment: Of course. You can try looking for the keyword "pseudodifferential calculus".

Comment: There exists a whole industry of "fractional calculus" with different definitions of what a "fractional derivative" is. For instance, as mentioned in the previous comment, using the Fourier transform there is a natural extension from integer to fractional derivatives.

Comment: @Gaussler try seeing Calculus of Finite differences

Comment: The [Wikipedia article for fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) mentions complex order derivatives too. No clue how that works.